# How to Identify the Entity Framework Core Provider from instance of DbContextOptions

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have configured my `CustomDbContext` to split the tables that store my object data into different schemas. It works just fine when I'm using the `SqlServer` provider, but whenever I try to use the `InMemory` provider, I get the following error:

```
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: lu.city'.
```

I'm sure this is due to the fact that SQLite does not use schemas. Is it possible to check the provider being used in an instance of `DbContextOptions`? If I had that info, I could just skip the schema assignments when using SQLite.

Comment: Add a constructor that passes in that info and store in a private variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CustomDbContext.Database.IsSqlite()
```

or

```
CustomDbContext.Database.ProviderName
```